# How to copy text to clipboard without any control in javascript(text not be assigned or store in a control like textbox)

Tags: javascript

```
var copyText = document.querySelector('.Ftxtbox-M');
copyText.select();
try {
    var successfull = document.execCommand('copy');
    var msg = successfull ? 'successful' : 'unsuccessful';
    alert('Copying text command was ' + msg);

}
catch (err) {
    alert('unable to copy');
}
```

I have done like this way bt i stored  in a textbox class `Ftxtbox-M`. How is it possible without kept in textbox?

Comment: _"my requirement is that..."_ __SO__ is not a free coding service...

Comment: thnks for ur valuable suggestion...